# how can i receive an image with mit appinventor

Tags: raspberry-pi3, app-inventor

I'm using Raspberry Pi to Take a photo and I want to build an android application that displays this photo, I have no experience in android so I'm using App Inventor to create the app, so I'm asking if it's possible to do that with The app inventor? any other solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From personal experience, though not with a Respberry Pi, is to tell AppInventor to send a text with a picture attachment, using the appropriate block language. If your Raspberry Pi doesn't have such capabilities, then this of course won't work.
Alternatively, you can have the Pi send information to one of AppInventor's free databases. When you do this, you will need to send  script to check every so often if a new photo has been taken/uploaded to the database, and tell the program to display the photo however large you want it in a window.
I would suggest making a button to close the window, as well.

I am not sure about the syntax for the database, but once you get the image from your database, the coding would be similar to as follows:
In 30 seconds, if new picture=true, get new picture. Either open or make visible a canvas with a button to close it, and define the window size if necessary. Make sure you check to keep the length and width ratios the same if you want to avoid image distortion.